# В лог файл пишет подобную ошибку: File does not exist: /var/www/site_host/site_host.com/articles

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Возникла проблема, открыл лог файл на сайте и увидел ну очень много подобных ошибок:

File does not exist: /var/www/site_host/site_host.com/articlesКак это можно отключить или поправить? Я понимаю, что не может найти файл или директорию, но при переходе на любую страницу пишет как ошибку, этих файлов или папок не может существовать. Если предложите создать пустые, то это не очень хорошая идея.

Answer (score 2):

По всей видимости, в коде Вашего проекта имеются ссылки на данное приложение /articles, которое являлось частью проекта когда-то.
Посмотрите в настройках - есть ли такое приложение и удалите его.

Comment: просто пишутся ошибки вообще на все страницы сайта, будь то каталожная страница или товарная. Как я понял он в первую очередь проверяет наличие по урлу файла или директории, а потом идет обработка php.

Comment: Так может, не от корня директорию задавать надо? Я не знаю, на чём у вас там сайт пашет, но вот в Wordpress - там конкретная иерахия.